# How to disable time calculation when copying files in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, file-transfer

When I copy large files on Windows 8, it always takes a long time to calculate the time remaining.

How can I disable this feature?

[image]

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding. The way Windows calculates the time remaining is by transferring the file and seeing how fast it goes. Disabling the calculation won't make the file transfer any faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding. The way Windows calculates the time remaining is by transferring the file and seeing how fast it goes. Disabling the calculation won't make the file transfer any faster.

Answer (score 2):

Time calculation is required to determine the I/O speed it is a default feature and cannot be turned off.
If you are willing try a 3rd party filemanager such as the 7zipFM from [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

IMO it offers much faster file copy  speeds

Comment: &zip transfer the files? I never used it for that as well as I know it only can compress the data?

Comment: no just transfer files .I am reffering to the 7zFM.exe.   Go to view-> select 2 panes . then browse to the directories that you want in the 2 panes  and drag and drop

Comment: Aha I missed the 7zipFM term I just thought about 7zip. :P